# Category Archives: Show posts categorized in parent category only

Tags: categories, theme-development, archives, theme-twenty-ten

When I view a category page in 2010 theme, it shown posts categorized in:

1. the category visible in url
2. child categories of 1.

I want to restrict the results to 1. only.
Please help.

Comment: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) says that `WP_Query('cat=4')` displays posts from child category by default. I couldn't find any _direct_ way to filter child category's posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is the *indirect* way I am using now. If there is any better answer please do share.

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());
    if (in_array($cat, $categories)) {
        ...
    }
} // end loop
```